# SUM COUNTIFS wrong value in excel online of google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-docs

i use sheets of google docs excel online.

i have value A1 - A6 with value

```
Column A
ax
ab
ac
ab
x
```

but formula in excel alawy return = 0.

```
 =SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A5;{"axx";"ab"})) // return = 0
```

link demo

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FP47-BjJJA44hH8cS9ocDHGmt9zXX1FL4ooKMRgOF30/edit?usp=sharing

why wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `ArrayFormula()` like-

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5,{"axx";"ab"})))
```

[image]

Comment: woy, thank you very much